# None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies: Firebase (~> 6.33.0), Firebase (= 6.33.0, ~> 6.33.0)

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I am implementing some of the firebase SDKs into my pods, but I am having an issue with versioning them. I want to set Firebase 6.33. I did check the pod spec of this version and updated my pods according to that.

```
pod 'Firebase', '~> 6.33.0'
pod 'FirebaseCore', '~> 6.10.3'
pod 'FirebasePerformance', '~> 3.3.0'
pod 'FirebaseRemoteConfig', '~> 4.9.0'
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics', '~> 6.8.3'
pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics', '~> 4.6.1'
```

When I use the codes above, it gives me this error on jenkins:

> None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies:
> Firebase (~> 6.33.0), Firebase (= 6.33.0, ~> 6.33.0).

I did `pod deintegrate` first and `pod install` to do a clean installation. It doesn't give the error on my MacBook but on jenkins.

podspec.json: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.33.0/Firebase.podspec.json

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`pod install --repo-update`

to update to recent published CocoaPods pods.

Comment: Before this command i run
```
sudo gem install ffi
```

Comment: Can confirm.

`sudo gem install ffi` and after that `pod install --repo-update` solved issue for me.

Comment: not working to me

Answer (score 65):

for Apple M1 users

Inside your ios Folder follow these commands in terminal

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

arch -x86_64 pod install
```

If not work try this

```
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update
```

for Apple Intel users

```
pod install --repo-update
```

Comment: "arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update" actually worked well for me, thanks

Comment: Finally, I found a solution that works for me - the problem was that I had Apple M1. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11):

For who is here with a Mac M1, trying to run `pod install --repo-update` in the VSCode terminal without success, the solution I found was:

- Find the native Terminal on Applications
- Make sure it is running with Rosetta (right click on Terminal > Obtain Information > Check Open With Rosetta)
- Open the terminal
- `cd path_to_your_ios_folder` and run  `pod install --repo-update`. That should work!

I am using:

```
Pod: 1.11.0
firebase_core: ^1.6.0
firebase_crashlytics: ^2.2.1
firebase_analytics: ^8.3.1
firebase_messaging: ^10.0.6
flutter: 2.2.3
```

Comment: this worked for me. Thanks a bunch. how did u find it?

Comment: I was using Android Studio terminal on Mac M1 and it did not work there as well. But running from native Terminal worked in one go. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This did it for me

```
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf Podfile.lock
rm -rf ~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org
pod cache clean --all
flutter clean
flutter pub get
pod repo update
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

Why all the different versions of firebase specified? For me I had three different Firebase related plugins (Analytics / Dynamiclinks / Firebasex). Each of these had a different source it was trying to pull from (some v 7.0.0 and some v 6.33.0). I went into the podfile and changed all of the versions to 6.33.0 and was able to build then.

Comment: If you take a look at the podspecs, you will see which other libraries are compatible with the one you choose. Not every version works with others so that’s why people adds the versioning.