# i can't run my app after i add firebase packages i still got errors

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

when I add new firebases package and run the application i get this error but when i remove the firebases package the app run normally

```
abdulazizraja@mbp-abdulaziz newozapp % flutter run
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             928ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`
    firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.7.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.7.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`
    firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.7.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `webview_flutter_wkwebview` from
    `.symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter_wkwebview/ios`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only
      performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is
      only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/8.6.1/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local
      because checking is only performed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Analytics":
      In Podfile:
        firebase_analytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`) was resolved to 8.3.3, which
        depends on
          Firebase/Analytics (= 8.7.0)

    None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Analytics (= 8.7.0)`.

    You have either:
     * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install
     --repo-update`.
     * mistyped the name or version.
     * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in
    `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in
    unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in
    `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in
    `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in
    resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in
    `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in
    resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in
    `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `12.0` on target `Runner` because no platform
    was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See
    `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
  pod repo update



Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro Max.
abdulazizraja@mbp-abdulaziz newozapp %
```

I have tried to do these steps

1- Delete the podfile.lock file
2- Delete the podfile file
3- Delete the pods file
4- Delete the .symlinks file
5- run flutter clean
6- run flutter pub get
7- cd ios
8-run pod install

when I run pod install I got this error

```
abdulazizraja@mbp-abdulaziz ios % pod install
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '8.7.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '8.7.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '8.7.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Analytics":
  In Podfile:
    firebase_analytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`) was resolved to 8.3.3, which depends on
      Firebase/Analytics (= 8.7.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Analytics (= 8.7.0)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

and this is my flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.2, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-arm, locale
    en-IQ)
    • Flutter version 2.5.2 at /Users/abdulazizraja/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 3595343e20 (2 weeks ago), 2021-09-30 12:58:18 -0700
    • Engine revision 6ac856380f
    • Dart version 2.14.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/abdulazizraja/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 13.0, Build version 13A233
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.61.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.27.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 13 Pro Max (mobile) • C3397850-A1E5-4CEA-B557-06DCCEB74A68 • ios
      • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-0 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                               •
      web-javascript • Google Chrome 94.0.4606.81

• No issues found!
```

This happens with all firebase packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try and run `pod install --repo-update`

If this doesn't work, and you are using one of the M1 Macs, then try and follow these steps.

- Find the native Terminal on Applications
- Make sure it is running with Rosetta (right click on Terminal > Obtain Information > Check Open With Rosetta
- Open the Terminal
- `cd path_to_your_ios_folder` and run `pod install --repo-update`

I found the answers right here, where there are other suggestions if these doesn't help: [None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies: Firebase (~> 6.33.0), Firebase (= 6.33.0, ~> 6.33.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64037496/none-of-your-spec-sources-contain-a-spec-satisfying-the-dependencies-firebase)